# Not getting field_with_errors for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3.2.2 and am not getting the field_with_errors div when the validation fails.

**views/sessions/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>

  <p><%= label_tag :email %><br />
  <%= email_field_tag :email %></p>

  <p><%= label_tag :password %><br />
  <%= password_field_tag :password %></p>

  <p><%= submit_tag "Log in" %></p>

<% end %>
```

**controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password]) && user.account.subdomain == request.subdomain
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to home_path
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email or password"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :password, :presence => true, :on => :create
```

I'm getting the flash message, but my view doesn't render the field_with_errors wrapper divs if the validation fails.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no longer included by default, you need to render your own error messages.

Here's some sample code generated in a scaffold for a `Post` model:

```
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You can then extract that into a partial for re-use with your other models.

Comment: Hmm... so I set my sessions_controller to use an @user instead of the local user, but when I submit an invalid form, I get `undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I assumed you were asking about model error messages in general. Your `user` instance won't have errors on it anyway because your authentication method either returns a user or nil. That's why the flash message for a login form is sufficient, either you logged in successfully or you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `field_with_errors` functionality only works with `form_for`. If you want it, you could change your `authenticate` method to add errors to the the `@user` object (it will have to be an instance variable for this to work), and then change your form to:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Log in" %></p>

<% end %>
```